# need to clear value of react-select after change in value of another react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

is it possible to clear the selected value of the react-select after a change in the value of another react select?
Basically, i want to perform the action that "Clear value" performs in react select

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. 
Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), 
as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. 
Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. If you use `Formik` you can do:

```
setFieldValue('nameOfField', null)
```

You can manage like this on change of field which you want to change.